# Limit r.v. of convergence almost surely has the same distribution of limit under convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $Y_n$ converge to $X$ almost surely. And suppose $Y_n$ converge to $Y$ in distribution. Do $X$ and $Y$ have same distribution? If not, with other condition like $Y$ is continuous everywhere or c.d.f. of $Y$ is not even, does it hold?
Since we know converge a.s. implies converge in distribution. Actually there is an example that if a sequence converges  in distribution to $A$ and $B$, then $A$ may not equal $B$ a.s. It seems here we need to show $P(\lim Y_n\le x)=\lim P(Y_n\le x)$. And dominated convergence theorem will help us. But I am a little confused that whether $\lim 1_{\{Y_n\le x\}}=1_{\{\lim Y_n\le x\}}$ holds.

Comment: Alternate route if you have other results at your disposal: If $Y_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely, then it converges in probability, and thus it converges in distribution. So $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Also, note that you only need to prove $P(\lim Y_n \le x) = \lim P(Y_n \le x)$ **for $x$ at which the cdf of $Y$ is continuous.** I don't think you can directly show $\lim 1_{Y_n \le x} = 1_{\lim Y_n \le x}$; I think you need to use continuity of the cdf at $x$. The lemma [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Proof_for_the_case_of_scalar_random_variables) may be helpful.